# Automatic ordinal for mySQL INSERT

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-order-by

I have a ranking database with (ordinal, user_id, score, time). I want to create a TRIGGER in mySQL which calculates the correct ordinal for an inserted entry depending on the score (and time with equal scores). Also the subsequent ordinals have to be shifted by 1 to ensure the ordinal is unique.
What is the best way to do so? Does it maybe make more sense to sort all data after the insert and recalculate all ordinals according to their order? How can i do that using a trigger?

Comment: You cannot modify the same table from a trigger that invoked the trigger in mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to mysql documentation on [restrictions in strored routines](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html)

> A stored function or trigger cannot modify a table that is already
>   being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the
>   function or trigger.

This means that you cannot use a trigger to achieve what you want. I would use a stored procedure, that

1. Takes the values to be inserted as parameters
2. Starts a transaction
3. Increases the ordinal for records where the ordinal greater than the to be inserted one by 1
4. Inserts the record
5. Commits the transaction